# installing kubuntu 14.04, need help with partitions/boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So, I'm very much new to linux and all of this. I like to program, so I thought a linux-based os would be a good idea, but I needed to keep microsoft for some more everyday things. So I tried to dual boot and I'm pretty sure I went wrong somewhere around the partitioning part of this whole install.

I started with booting from a usb that I loaded with the iso that's online. It loaded fine, I got to the installer, selected manual partition, and here's what I did from there (note, my computer says `efi` in the `setuppact` file, and it seems that it's gpt as well. That said, I don't know what that means, but from what I've looked up I guess it's supposed to affect how I partition). I set up a 8gb partition for swap, a 20gb ext4 for root tagged with /, a 1mb for `biosgrub` (it recommended that I add that one), and an 8 gb ext4 tagged with /home. for the boot loader install I kept it at the default, which was the one at the top of the partition list (forget what it's called, I think just sda/hd without any numbers).

I hit install, and it says it worked out well, except grub won't open up when I boot regardless of what buttons I do or don't press during startup. I can only conclude that I screwed something up at that point. I downloaded the correct version so I don't think it's that. Maybe somebody has another idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my computer says "efi" in the setuppact file, and it seems that it's gpt as well

This description suggests that Windows is probably installed in EFI mode. This is a critical detail, so I recommend you verify it, as described on [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html), among other places.

> a 1mb for biosgrub (it recommended that I add that one)

If the installer is suggesting a "biosgrub" partition, then that indicates that the installer booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Such a boot is at odds with an EFI-mode boot of Windows and would explain your failure to boot.

If this analysis is correct, you have a number of recovery options:

- Disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or some similar term) in your firmware and re-install Ubuntu. A full re-install is overkill, but since you presumably haven't yet customized your installation or done much with it, you might consider it.
- Disable the CSM in your firmware and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program from a boot of the Ubuntu installer in "try before installing" mode. This *should* get Ubuntu booting in EFI mode, but there are a number of ways it can go wrong. In most cases you'll still be able to boot Windows, but there's a small chance Boot Repair will end up creating serious new problems. I don't want to blow this risk out of proportion, though; this procedure will *probably* work fine.
- If it's not already disabled, disable Secure Boot in your firmware. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a medium from that, and boot it. This should enable you to boot into either Windows or Ubuntu. If both work, install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package. This approach eliminates the small risk of the preceding one because the USB/CD-R boot of rEFInd serves as a test of what it will do once it's installed on your hard disk, enabling you to abort before you touch the disk, should you not like what you see.

There are variants and additional options. For instance, you could use rEFInd to boot once and use that to install GRUB 2 (Ubuntu's default boot loader).

Note that, if my analysis is correct, your initial problem was caused by enabling the CSM. Many pages recommend doing this as a routine part of installing Ubuntu, but the advice is misguided, as I describe on [this page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) That's why two of my procedures specify disabling the CSM -- unless you disable it or use an EFI-only boot procedure (which rEFInd is), you can't be sure you'll boot the Ubuntu installer in EFI mode, so you could end up back in the same boat.

Comment: Thanks! Your deduction was correct. After going into the bios, the CSM was enabled, but the option was locked as per the manufacturer, so I went ahead to your page,  downloaded the boot manager, and it worked perfectly. Couldn't have been better.